# How to create RSA signature in Java with encapsulated data

Tags: java, openssl, rsa

I am trying to generate RSA signature that encapsulates data in Java, so the data can be recovered with OpenSSL command:

```
$ openssl pkeyutl -verifyrecover -pubin -inkey public.pem -in signature
```

With generated key pair for sign/verify purpose in Java I'm creating signature:

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
signature.initSign(privateKey);
signature.update(content);
byte[] signatureBytes = signature.sign();
```

This approach doesn't encapsulate date and creates detached signature which can we verified with:

```
$ openssl dgst -verify public.pem -signature signature data.txt
```

What's the correct way to encapsulate data with RSA signature in Java, so it can be extracted with `openssl-pkeyutl`?

Comment: [`Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA")`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#signature-algorithms) (case-insensitive). Data is limited to the size of the RSA key (i.e. the modulus) minus 11 bytes (octets).

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 thanks but this doesn't seem to work, getting an exception when trying to recover:
```Public Key operation error
4379872940:error:04FFF06A:rsa routines:CRYPTO_internal:block type is not 01:/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/38cf1d983f/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-56.60.2/libressl-2.8/crypto/rsa/rsa_pk1.c:103:
4379872940:error:04FFF072:rsa routines:CRYPTO_internal:padding check failed:/System/Volumes/Data/SWE/macOS/BuildRoots/38cf1d983f/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/libressl/libressl-56.60.2/libressl-2.8/crypto/rsa/rsa_eay.c:680:```

Comment: **Works for me**: tested with Oracle standard providers in 8u5 8u301 11.0.1 and 17.0.1, and BouncyCastle providers 1.52 and 1.69, to several versions of OpenSSL (real OpenSSL not LibreSSL which I don't have and theoretically _could_ have a bug here but that's very unlikely) except 1.1.1 because it added a spurious length check that blocks testing (and even there `rsautl` works). **Make sure you have correctly-matching keys**; most padding errors on RSA verify or decrypt are due to mismatched keys.

Comment: Thank you @dave_thompson_085, you are right! `NONEwithRSA` is correct and now it becomes quite obvious - since data is not hashed it's possible to recover it.